# Python can't find character

Tags: python, string

I've written a simple statement that does something when I take a string from some html source, but when I write:

```
if 'p\xd1\x83\xd0\xb1.' in item:
#other code
```

the code in the *if* doesn't run.

That's how I take the source:

```
source=urlopen(link).read().decode('utf-8')
```

P.S. I split the source in a list of string then I loop through it.. item is a portion of the entire html source

EDIT: in my case item is somethig like:

```
<p> руб.230 </p>
```

Comment: And what's `item`? Show us an `item` for which you expect the `if` statement to be executed. I think I know what your problem here is, but I won't answer until I am certain.

Comment: edited... It wasn't clear sorry

Comment: can you provide a printout of an example `item` where you expect it to work and it's not working?

Comment: Or provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with an explicit example link and the code of how you go from `source` to `item`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`p\xd1\x83\xd0\xb1.` is a string of bytes. By decoding it as UTF-8, you convert the string of bytes into a string of unicode characters:

```
>>> 'p\xd1\x83\xd0\xb1.'.decode('utf-8')
u'p\u0443\u0431.'
>>> print u'p\u0443\u0431.'
pуб.
```

They're not the same. If you want to check for the existence of the substring in the list, either treat the HTML as bytes and don't `decode` it, or decode it and check if the Unicode characters are a substring:

```
if u'p\u0443\u0431.' in text:
    ...
```

Or more readably:

```
if u'руб.' in text:
   ...
```

You may need to declare a character encoding at the top of your Python script if you include the unicode characters in your source:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Also, that Latin `p` should probably be a Cyrillic `р`. The two look the same, but they're different characters entirely.